# jQuery auto resizing not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add an image inside a div(#bg) using jquery to create an auto resizing webpage. So far I have coded like this but the auto resizing have some problems. If I manually add the image to div then everything works fine. I am a novice in jquery if you can elaborate your answers that will be great. Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<div id="bg">​
</div>`
```

CSS

```
#bg { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; }
.bgwidth { width: 100%; }
.bgheight { height: 100%; }`
```

jquery

```
$(window).load(function() { 

    $('#bg').prepend('<img src="Background.jpg" id="bg" alt="" />')

var theWindow        = $(window),
    $bg              = $("#bg"),
    aspectRatio      = $bg.width() / $bg.height();

function resizeBg() {

    if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
        $bg
            .removeClass()
            .addClass('bgheight');
    } else {
        $bg
            .removeClass()
            .addClass('bgwidth');
    }

}

theWindow.resize(resizeBg).trigger("resize");

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written some days ago a similar function:

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://ge.tt/api/1/files/1jN8IzR/0/blob?download" class='bg'>
```

**CSS**
*not really needed*

```
.bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1
}
```

**JS**

```
var fitPic = (function() {
    var winW = $(window).width(),
        winH = window.innerHeight || $(window).height(); // `innerHeight` for mobile safari

    $(".bg").each(function() {

        var elem = $(this),
            elemW = elem.width(),
            elemH = elem.height(),

            imgW = (elemW * winH) / elemH,
            imgH = (elemH * winW) / elemW,

            newW = imgH < winH ? imgW : winW,
            newH = imgH < winH ? winH : imgH;

        this.style.width = newW + "px";
        this.style.height = newH + "px";

    });
});

$(window).on('load resize', fitPic);
```

Comment: If I add the img in HTML my code is working perfectly, but I want to add it through jQuery. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much yckart. Your solution worked perfectly. After you have supplied fiddle link I was able to understand your script fully. As I am a novice it took some time to understand your script. Many thanks and sorry for the delay.